# Hide some lines in odoo treeview

Tags: python, xml, treeview, odoo

I am trying to hide some lines in a tree view according to a specific flag, here is my tree view's xml code :

```
<record model='ir.ui.view' id='my_object_tree'>
    <field name="name">my_object.tree</field>
    <field name="model">my_object</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml" >
        <tree string="title" attrs="{'invisible': [('my_flag','=',False)]}">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="my_flag"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

but it seems that "invisible" doesn't work here,
I can hide all fields but I in that case empty lines will appear in the tree view.
Is there any other solution please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What objects appear in a list view is determined by a domain that is a part of the *action* definition:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="my_object_action">
    <field name="name">my_object.action</field>
    <field name="res_model">my_object</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[
        ('my_flag', '=', True)
    ]</field>
</record>
```

Comment: thanks it works (in condition that 'my_flag is' a m2o field), but the lines are no longer clickables, can't I change this please ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the lines are no longer clickables" (what does "clickables" mean?). Specifying a domain on an action shouldn't change anything else about a list view.

Comment: I mean that in the normal case, when you click on a line in tree view, the form view of this line should appear

Comment: Adding a domain wouldn't change that. Go back to a code that was working and just add the domain, without changing anything else.

Comment: this is what I did and it works perfectly thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can set DOMAIN in action like i have used...

```
<record id="action_hr_employee" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Employee</field>
        <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('type', '=', 'temporary')]</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
        <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click to add a new temporary Employee.</p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

above code is about to display only those records which are type = temporary